# How to skip only testcase and run deploy phase using gitlab ci yaml

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to skip the test case alone for MR which is been titled as WIP (work in progress) where I tried this one.

[image]

can anyone please suggest a better option to handle this case.

Comment: Try not using images, since the image contains text, you can add it directly to the question

Comment: anyone, please provide a solution for this case.